# Shared Preferences not retrieving value on re-opening activity

Tags: java, android, performance, sharedpreferences

I am creating an app in which coins/points increases on watching reward video ads and those coins/points are to be saved.

For example: every time on button click the coins value increases to 10 points. Now when I completely destroy the app and open it again, the points value should show the same, not zero. 
I was trying to implement shared preferences to save the coins but after exiting the app, when i re-open it the coins becomes zero as usual.

Here's my code

```
public class BooksActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {
private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;
private TextView mText;
private int coinCount;
private CardView book;


public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_books);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, R.string.mypublisherid);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
    coinCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("coins", coinCount);

    mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mText);
    coinCount = 0;
    mText.setText(" " + coinCount);
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("coins", coinCount);
    editor.commit();


    mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);



    loadRewardedVideoAd();


    book = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.book_one);
    book.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (coinCount <= 29) {
                //if(coinCount <30) {
                new MaterialStyledDialog.Builder(BooksActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Not Enough Coins")
                        .setDescription("Watch Ads To earn coins")
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.money)
                        .withIconAnimation(true)
                        .withDialogAnimation(true)
                        .setHeaderColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
                        .setPositiveText("Of Course!")
                        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeText("Not Now")
                        .onNeutral(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                        .show();

            } else {
                coinCount = coinCount - 30;
                mText.setText(String.valueOf(coinCount));

            }
        }
    });
}


private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(R.string.mypublisherid,
            new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    loadRewardedVideoAd();

}

@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
    addCoins(rewardItem.getAmount());

}

private void addCoins(int amount) {
    coinCount += amount;
    mText.setText(" " + coinCount);

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

    Toast.makeText(BooksActivity.this, "Check your network connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.resume(this);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.pause(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.destroy(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void startVideoAd(View view) {
    mRewardedVideoAd.show();
}
```

}

kindly do tell what was done wrong by me in the code.

Comment: its seems like your code is ok, maybe it because you set coinCount to Zero then print? have you tested it with break points? try removing coinCount = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1, initialize cointCount before using it in onCreate

```
private int cointCount = 0
```

Step 2, don't override the stored value in `onCreate`, so remove these lines from your `onCreate` method

```
coinCount = 0;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("coins", coinCount);
editor.commit();
```

Step 3, update it in addCoins

```
private void addCoins(int amount) {
    coinCount += amount;
    mText.setText(" " + coinCount);

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("coins", coinCount);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Alternately, put the update code in `onPause` so you don't run it as often.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I earlier forgot to remove coinCount to zero

Answer (score 2):

Every time your `Activity` is created, you re-write your preference value to 0. So every time the `Activity` is created your count according to `SharedPreferences` is 0.

In your function `addCoins()` you increment your value, but you never update the value in `SharedPreferences`. If the goal is to retain your value across multiple instances of your `Activity` starting, you need to stop re-writing the value to 0 every time you create the `Activity`. Then if you want your incremented value to be updated in `SharedPreferences` you need to either update the value in your `SharedPreferences` every time you increment it or whenever your `Activity` pauses in `OnPause()`.

Answer (score 1):

You only save coinCount using SharedPreference editor in onCreate, right after setting it to 0. It works as intended.

Try saving it after coinCount actually changes.

Comment: I earlier used  shared preferences inside private void addCoins . It didn't work. On closing the activity it became 0

Comment: In onCreate you set it to 0 again AND save it as 0 to preferences. Remove putInt and commit in onCreate, it doesn't serve any purpose.